# Стилизация кнопок закрыть/свернуть для wpf

Tags: wpf, visual-studio, дизайн, стилизация

У приложения есть стандартные кнопки свернуть и закрыть. Но меня они не устраивают. Нужно сделать свои кнопки. Поставил задачу сделать кнопки с прозрачным фоном.

Должно выглядеть так:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

А при наведении курсора цвет фона и значка менялся:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Начал делать реализацию так:

```
<Window x:Class="ProgramProject.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:ProgramProject"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="421" Width="425" ResizeMode="NoResize" Background="{x:Null}" WindowStyle="None">
    <Grid>
        <Border CornerRadius="12">
            <Border.Background>
                <LinearGradientBrush EndPoint="0.5,1" StartPoint="0.5,0">
                    <GradientStop Color="#2e75b6" Offset="0.5" />
                    <GradientStop Color="#1f4e79" Offset="1" />
                </LinearGradientBrush>
            </Border.Background>
        </Border>
        <Rectangle Fill="#FFF4F4F5" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="60" Stroke="Black" Opacity="0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="425" MouseLeftButtonDown="Rectangle1_PreviewMouseLeftButtonDown">
        <Grid Height="20" Margin="382,10,23,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" MouseDown="Grid1_MouseDown" >
            <Button Opacity="0" Content="" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="-13,-10,-12,-8" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="45" Height="38"/>
            <Path  Stretch="Fill" Fill="#FFFFFF" Data="F1 M 25.9166,22.1667L 37.9999,33.25L 49.0832,22.1668L 53.8332,26.9168L 42.7499,38L 53.8332,49.0834L 49.0833,53.8334L 37.9999,42.75L 26.9166,53.8334L 22.1666,49.0833L 33.25,38L 22.1667,26.9167L 26.9166,22.1667 Z " Margin="3.5,3.5,3.5,4.5"/>
        </Grid>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

Однако, так как я новенький в wpf, у меня возникло несколько вопросов:

1. Нет ли более простого способа, чем рисовать крестик и палку кодом? Может эти кнопки уже есть?
2. Как выполнить изменения стиля сразу 2-ух объектов? В интернете есть примеры с изменением цвета фона кнопки при наведении, однако те примеры с наведением на кнопку. У меня же наведение может коснуться самого значка на кнопке и не факт, что указатель будет находиться за кнопкой.
3. Правильно ли я вообще начал реализовывать это дело. Помещать кнопку и значок в grid?

Я не жду, что кто-то сделает готовый пример (хотя был бы очень признателен реализованному простому способу). Мне главное, чтобы натолкнули на верный путь, пояснив вопросы.

Comment: [WPF: Нестандартное окно](https://habrahabr.ru/post/158561/)

Comment: Рекомендую отличный [видеоурок(и)](https://youtu.be/TDOxHx-AMqQ?t=1h31m32s), правда на англ.языке :)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Для начала, всё не проще, а сложнее.

Если просто нарисовать кнопки, то они не попадут в non-client area. Поэтому вы должны поместить их туда, используя `WindowChrome`, например, как описано в этом вопросе: [WPF Создание кастомного стиля окна с тенью](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/675238/10105).

Затем, по поводу отрисовки крестиков. Нет, в WPF нету встроенного крестика, потому что он для каждой системы свой (посмотрите, как выглядит он на Windows 7, и как на Windows 10), а также зависит от системных настроек (выбранной цветовой схемы, включенного или нет режима увеличения и/или повышенной контрастности и т. д.). Одна строчка нарисованного руками крестика — не слишком сложное требование.

Я бы тем не менее поместил крестик *внутрь* кнопки, и подменил шаблон:

```
<Button Height="25" Width="25">
    <Button.Template>
        <ControlTemplate TargetType="Button">
            <Border x:Name="Bd" Background="Transparent">
                <Path x:Name="Pt" Data="M0,0 M0.2,0.2 L 0.8,0.8 M0.2,0.8 L0.8,0.2 M1,1"
                      Stretch="Uniform" Stroke="Black" StrokeThickness="2"/>
            </Border>
            <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True">
                    <Setter TargetName="Bd" Property="Background" Value="Red"/>
                    <Setter TargetName="Pt" Property="Stroke" Value="White"/>
                </Trigger>
            </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
        </ControlTemplate>
    </Button.Template>
</Button>
```

[image: анимашка]

---

Оффтопик: Вы, судя по коду, пишете XAML через визуальный редактор. Это приводит к достаточно неоптимальному коду, и выводит из игры layout manager. (Например, вы размещаете кнопку на экране конструкциями наподобие `Margin="382,10,23,0"`. Не делайте так, используйте layout manager вручную.)

Comment: Отлично. Это то, что мне нужно. Знаю, что не по теме вопроса, но всё же. У меня есть `Rectangle`, который был добавлен, чтобы перемещать окно в пространстве при зажатой кнопке. Правильный ли я элемент выбрал и его настройки (как по мне, так не логично вставлять элемент с цветом, а потом скрывать этот цвет через Opacity. 

Тупой вопрос. Как вообще рисовать такие вещи, как крестик? Как Вы это делаете?

Comment: У приложения несколько окон. Можно CTRL+C - CTRL+V, но к чему столько лишнего кода? Можно ли это оптимизировать? Сделать кнопки на все окна (с возможностью добавления в некоторые из окон новых кнопок рядом (например, кнопку развернуть))?

Comment: @EgorTrutnev: Не совсем правильно. Для перемещения окна используется регион Caption в non-client area. Соответственно вам нужно настроить `CaptionHeight` в `WindowChrome`.

Comment: @EgorTrutnev: Ну, рисовать крестик просто: поставить точку в левом верхнем углу, провести линию в правый нижний, потом поставить точку в левом верхнем, и провести линию в правый нижний.

Comment: @EgorTrutnev: Никаких Ctrl-C / Ctrl-V! Определите **стиль** окна (он как раз и дан в [примере](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/676221/10105)), и примените его ко всем окнам.

Comment: Спасибо. Единственный недочёт, что я нашёл. Цвет фона меняется только в случае, если указатель попадает на символ в кнопке, а не на саму кнопку. Можно ли это исправить?

Comment: @EgorTrutnev: Хм, сейчас перепроверю.

Comment: @EgorTrutnev: И правда! Починил. Нужно было добавить `Background="Transparent"` в `Border`.

Comment: Спасибо огромное! Начинаю разбираться

Comment: @EgorTrutnev: Пожалуйста!