# Обработка не клиентской части в WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, .net

При полной кастомизации окна в WPF приходится отказываться от его стандартных элементов, так как они не поддаются изменению.

Делаю я это следующим образом:

```
AllowsTransparency="True"
WindowStyle="None"
```

При попытке воссоздать элементы окна, но со своими стилями, вычитал, что по стандарту не клиентская часть обрабатывается на более низком уровне, и именно в связи с этим средствами WPF её не изменить.

Суть вопроса в следующем: как с помощью C# обратится к этому более низкому уровню и достать функции которые отвечают за полноценную работу окна(перетаскивание, изменение состояния, изменение размера и т.д.), во избежание конструирования велосипедов?

Comment: Дубликат? https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/675238/10105

Comment: @VladD, не совсем, в моём вопросе речь о функциях WinAPI, которые выполняют вышеупомянутые задачи. О том, что это именно WinAPI, я узнал уже после публикации вопроса. На данный момент остаётся неясным, какие именно функции использовать и как именно(я с этим ещё не сталкивался).

Comment: Ну там в ответе как раз и пример того, как средствами WPF кастомизировать неклиентскую часть окна. А тому источнику, где вы вычитали, будто бы на уровне WPF это не возможно, больше не доверяйте.

Comment: Так пробовали ? https://habrahabr.ru/post/158561/

Comment: @VladD, вы правы, в таком случае стоит закрыть вопрос.