# Создание CaptionHeight "неправильной" формы

Tags: c#, wpf, .net

Добрый день!

Переписал макет окна, но сейчас возник вопрос, как изменить форму CaptionHeight окна.
Вот форма того, как желательно выгдяеть (темная область):
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Так как в белых областях возникла потребность разместить другие элементы.

Comment: А это не помогло: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/676221/10105?

Comment: @Vlad: сейчас попробую

Comment: @VladD: благодарю за ссылку. Оказалось нужно добавить только одну строку shell:WindowChrome.IsHitTestVisibleInChrome="True" и все будет отлично работать.

Comment: Отлично! Напишете ответ для благодарных потомков?

Comment: @Vlad: конечно)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

В .Net 4.0 данный вопрос решается добавлением строки:

```
shell:WindowChrome.IsHitTestVisibleInChrome="True"
```

в свойствах элемента, который стоит разместить в области, попадающие под действие CaptionHeight. Тогда данный элемент становится активным, и при зажатии мыши на нем нельзя перемещать окно.

[Вот ссылка по теме.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2967218/window-out-of-the-screen-when-maximized-using-wpf-shell-integration-library/2975574#2975574)