# C# WPF максимизация окна когда WindowStyle == None

Tags: c#, wpf

Есть главное окно (WindowStyle = None) которому я задал

```
 Application.Current.MainWindow.MaxWidth = SystemParameters.WorkArea.Width + 7;
 Application.Current.MainWindow.MaxHeight = SystemParameters.WorkArea.Height + 12;
```

и в StateChanged добавил

```
  if(Application.Current.MainWindow.WindowState == WindowState.Normal) {
    this.Border.Margin = new Thickness(0);
  }
  else if(Application.Current.MainWindow.WindowState == WindowState.Maximized) {
    this.Border.Margin = new Thickness(6, 6, 0, 0);
  }
```

где Border - рамка окна и все стало на свои места когда изменяю WindowState.
Но окно переходит в Maximized еще когда мышкой потащить окно и ударить в вверх робочего стола и вот сдесь проблема, не хватает width. Почему? Как сделать нормально?

Application.Current.MainWindow.Width и
Application.Current.MainWindow.Height когда

`Application.Current.MainWindow.WindowState = WindowState.Maximized;`

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

1687x1022

а когда ударить мышкой

1260x737

при разрешении екрана 1680x1050

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/676221/220553

Comment: @EvgeniyZ не помогло, максимизация мышкой также криво