# Растяжения окна

Tags: c#, wpf

Я создаю собственный стиль окна. Вот мой код

```
<Window x:Class="WindowStyle.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WindowStyle"
    mc:Ignorable="d"
    Title="MainWindow"
    WindowStyle="None"
    AllowsTransparency="True"
    Background="Transparent"
    Height="400"
    Width="600">



<Grid DataContext="{Binding ElementName=root}">
    <Border Visibility="{Binding Visibility}">
        <Border Background="AliceBlue"
            CornerRadius="10,10,10,10" VerticalAlignment="Top">
            <StackPanel Height="40px">
                <Grid>

                </Grid>
            </StackPanel>
        </Border>
    </Border>

    <StackPanel Margin="0,30,0,0" Background="AntiqueWhite" VerticalAlignment="Stretch"></StackPanel>
</Grid>
```

После запуска программы окно нельзя растянуть.
Как это исправить не используя ResizeMode = "CanResizeWithGrip"

Comment: Посмотрите [это](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/675238/10105) и связанные вопросы.