# Окно некорректно разворачивается(WindowState.Maximized) C# WPF

Tags: c#, wpf

Есть такое окно без рамки [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```
<Window x:Class="DatingClient.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:DatingClient"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        Title="MainWindow"
        Height="450"
        MinHeight="450"
        Width="800"
        MinWidth="800"
        WindowStyle="None"
        ResizeMode="CanResize"
        FontFamily="Fonts/#Montserrat">
    <WindowChrome.WindowChrome>
        <WindowChrome CaptionHeight="0"/>
    </WindowChrome.WindowChrome>
```

Вся проблема в том, что при разворачивании(максимизации) с помощью WindowState.Maximized Кусочек верхней панели с заголовком и кнопками уходит за границы экрана. На скриншоте ниже видно, что где-то 10 пикселей за экран уходит, что делать?
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 1):

Это известный эффект, и, кажется, даже документированный. Рассчитывайте на него, и компенсируйте сдвиги.

Например, можно сделать через стиль:

```xaml
<Style TargetType="{x:Type Window}" x:Key="ModifiedWindow">
    <Setter Property="WindowChrome.WindowChrome">
        <Setter.Value>
            <!-- тут WindowChrome для нормального случая -->
            <WindowChrome .../>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
    <Style.Triggers>
        <Trigger Property="WindowState" Value="Maximized">
            <Setter Property="WindowChrome.WindowChrome">
                <Setter.Value>
                    <!-- тут WindowChrome для максимизированного окна -->
                    <WindowChrome .../>
                </Setter.Value>
            </Setter>
        </Trigger>
    </Style.Triggers>
</Style>
```

Если вы не хотите менять `WindowChrome`, можно в триггере сделать повыше верхний элемент окна.

---

Информация и длинное обсуждение есть, например, [тут](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/676221/10105).